# VARCHAR(MAX) taking more space than NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, disk-space, blob, unicode

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition that has ~100GB of data. Most of this data is attributed to a single `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column which has an average length of 4500 characters. It stores data compressed by an application that has no need for Unicode characters.

Since [`NVARCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) takes two bytes per character and [`VARCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) takes one, I surmised I could cut down on some storage by switching the table over. However, once I altered the column to be `VARCHAR(MAX)`, the table ballooned to 155GB.

I am aware SQL may use [Unicode Compression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835(v=sql.110).aspx) but the documentation states this does not apply to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` so it couldn't have been in use.

So why has my table grown so much in size?

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [RecordLocator] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SystemId] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [EventXML] [nvarchar](max) NULL, --Not XML, compressed XML as characters
    [UpdateUTCTimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [DeleteDate] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecordLocator] ASC,
    [CreateDate] ASC,
    [SystemId] ASC,
    [DeleteDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 75) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Additional notes:**

- Table design is not ideal, I am also working on getting that changed with the third party developers.
- Table is partitioned on DeleteDate - also not ideal but required as of now to efficiently swap out old data
- Table does not have row or page compression enabled
- Table row growth before and after table alter is negligible
- D'oh, I did run `sp_spaceused` and failed to add the output:

  ```
   name   rows        reserved        data            index_size  unused
   Table  11407899    160531008 KB    159465328 KB    525200 KB   540480 KB
  ```